# how can I return all the elements of an array with the first letter as a capital letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, capitalization

I am trying to get the first letter of each element in the below array to return a capital letter but only seem to be able to return the second word

```
var clenk = ["ham","cheese"];
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < clenk.length; i++) {
var result = clenk[i].replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });

}

alert(result);
```

Comment: You're returning the result. 
Call alert on the clenk array, now that you've done the replace on it.
`alert(clenk);`

Comment: Your `alert()` is outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
var clenk = ["ham","cheese"];
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < clenk.length; i++) {
    var result = clenk[i].replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });
    alert(result);
}
```

Put your `alert(result)` inside the loop, otherwise you're only getting the last `result` out.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) may be simpler here:

```
var results = clenk.map(function (word) {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String.prototype.toUpperCaseWords = function () {
  return this.replace(/\w+/g, function(a){ 
    return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1).toLowerCase()
  })
}
```

and use it like :-

```
"MY LOUD STRING".toUpperCaseWords(); // Output: My Loud String
"my quiet string".toUpperCaseWords(); // Output: My Quiet String

var stringVariable = "First put into a var";

stringVariable.toUpperCaseWords(); // Output: First Put Into A Var
```

[Source](https://blog.smalldo.gs/2014/06/easily-add-phps-ucwords-ucfirst-to-javascript/)

Comment: @saj for your kind information that's upper case, mine answer will capitalize first character for each word